# add items to OrderedDict via function call

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, ordereddictionary, xmltodict

I'm new to python and don't know a lot about data structures, I'm trying to append extra items to an ordered dictionary via a call to a function. The goal is making an xml file with xmltodict.

```
OrderedDict([
        ('@attr1', 'aa'),
        ('@attr2', 'bb'),
        ('@attr3', 'cc'),           
        add_items()
     ])

def add_items():
    items = ('item1', 'val1'),
            ('item2', 'val2')
return items
```

If items contains just item1, a single tuple?, it works. But if I add a second tuple (item2) then it doesn't. I can't get it to work with item2 included whatever I do, what data structure do items have to be in to make this work or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `*add_items()`? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: I can't believe that worked, I need to read up on this unpacking -  thankyou